# How can I make a primary key as AUTOINCREMENT

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, auto-increment

I have table in Database and the primry key is 'ID', Just I want to ask how can I make it AUTOINCREMENT

I know that's esay Q, but I dont know how can I do it.

thanks

Comment: what kind of db? Sql Server? Oracle? Etc...

Comment: This will depend on what database system you are using. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I use SQL Server 2005 which coming with VB.NET 2008

Answer (score 16):

There is a property "Identity Specification". Expand that one, you can chose Increment value, and Increment Seed

Comment: This is for SQL Server by the way.

Comment: I'd bet sql server since it is asp.net

Comment: I do .NET with Oracle, see my other answer. I was just assuming SQL Server somehow.....

Comment: I expanded "Identity Specification"  and try to edit "Identity increment" but I cannt do that, becuse it's not enlighten

Comment: First change "Is identity specification" to: Yes

Comment: doubleclick NO, then it will turn into YES

Comment: do not forget that the data type should be integer :)

Answer (score 9):

In Sql Server define the column like this...

```
[PrimaryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

Then you can add a constraint making it the primary key.

Answer (score 2):

Since you listed ASP.NET, I'm going to assume you are running a SQL Server 2005/2008. If you want to use the GUI, then follow these steps:

- Open the table in design view
- Click on the "ID" column
- Confirm the type is an Int
- Select "Yes" under Identity Specification

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle it is a bit more non-trivial. You first have to create a [sequence](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php) and then a [trigger](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/index.php).

Comment: did you mean to say "non-trivial"?

Answer (score 0):

Go to column properties. There you have Identity specification properties. Expand the same. Next you set Is Identity as Yes. Then you can set Identity Increment value and Identity seed value as per requirement. By default it gets set to 1.