# How can I make a primary key as AUTOINCREMENT in vb.net 2008?

Tags: asp.net, linq, auto-increment

I have table in a DB and the primary key is the 'TID' column,
and I want to make it as AUTOINCREMENT, but I can't, because the "Identity specification" is turned off!

See this picture:  http://www.rofof.com/img2/6xsbuy6.gif

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958120/how-can-i-make-a-primary-key-as-autoincrement

Comment: Please don't ask the same question over and over.

Comment: I am sorry, but I note my old post was die so I post new one. rellay I'm sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make it an `int` column or other number type rather than an `nchar` column.  I suspect `nchar(10)` is the wrong type for your other columns as well:  you probably want `nvarchar` columns for your name fields and you'll want to allow space for a little more than 10 characters.

---

You're trying to set a value for the ID column yourself.  When you use autoincrement columns, you don't put the ID column in your insert statement at all.

Comment: yes, that's is! thanks. but how can I set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON? see this please: http://www.rofof.com/img2/6amojc6.gif

Answer (score 1):

Use a type that supports autoincrement, such as **int** or **bigint**.