# Auto Increment in SQL server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How to add auto incrementing property to primary key of a table in Sql Server 2005 ?
I have ProductID as primary key. I want to increment its value by 1 everytime a record is added. I didn't use IDENTITY keyword while creating table.

Comment: check this out maybe helpfull
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958120/how-can-i-make-a-primary-key-as-autoincrement

Comment: I think this will help: [Adding an identity to an existing column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot posted about this either here in SO or in other places.
What you are looking for is exactly this

[`how to set auto increment after creating a table without any data loss?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084572/how-to-set-auto-increment-after-creating-a-table-without-any-data-loss/6086661#6086661)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everyone . i have found another way of adding IDENTITY property without sql commands.

In SQL Server Management console , go to Object Explorer->Select your Database->Select your Table->Right click on the Column on which Identity property has to be specified->Choose Modify option.
In column Poperties window , scroll to Identity Specification . Change value of IsIdentity to Yes and specify seed and increment values and save.