# Increment by 1 ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a little problem in ASP.NET. I'm trying to get the MAX number in a column and then increment it by 1.
Like this in example:

```
SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();

string db = "instert into FJ(C1, C2, C3) values (@c1 , @c2 ,@c3)";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(db, con);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c1", TextBox1.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c2", com .CommandText = "declare @a float set @a = (select MAX(C2) from FJ)+1 INSERT INTO [FJ]([C2]) VALUES (@a)");
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c3", TextBox3.Text);

com.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

The thing that column C2 is incremented by 1 but other columns are null. If I comment C2 line TextBox1 and 3 are added to the database.
What is the problem?

**P.S. I'm not allowed to edit the database. I need to make it in ASP.NET code.**

Comment: Why not define an IDENTITY column directly in the database?

Comment: Because I'm not allowed to edit the database. I need to make it in ASP.NET code. That's what my supervisor told me. :/

Comment: The problem with that is that with concurrency (multiple concurrent uses), this can _easily_ fail if not managed by the DB. Right tool for the right job - if you are not allowed to change the DB, work with someone who _can_.

Comment: But is there any way how to increment by one without making other columns to be NULL?

Comment: In the table design - making the column an auto-incrementing IDENTITY column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the C2 increment can be set in the Database side. no need to these calculations.

[How can I make a primary key as AUTOINCREMENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958120/how-can-i-make-a-primary-key-as-autoincrement)

Update :
then you are doing it wrong . you are changing the command in :

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c2", com .CommandText = "declare @a float set @a = (select MAX(C2) from FJ)+1 INSERT INTO [FJ]([C2]) VALUES (@a)");
```

that's why other columns are null.

it should be :

```
SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();

string db = "declare @a float; set @a = (select MAX(C2) from FJ)+1;instert into FJ(C1, C2, C3) values (@c1 , @a ,@c3)";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(db, con);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c1", TextBox1.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c3", TextBox3.Text);

com.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: I know primary key but I'm not allowed to edit the database. I need to make it in ASP.NET code. That's what my supervisor told me. :/

Comment: It doesn't work. Now the C2 column is NULL and TextBox 1 and 3 are added to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have experienced a similar situation.

Using an identity is always a good solution, but, when an `INSERT` operation fails, it looses the new `ID` generated!

Looking into your `T-SQL`, I see a problem: What will happen when two operations starts on the "same" time, i.e., when the last value for the `C2` column be, let's say 10? There will be either two rows with the `11` value or if the column has a `unique index` the `INSERT` that started first will have the new value and the second will fail... It would cause several damages, I think.

What I suggest is to change the `INSERT` statement to be this way:

```
INSERT INTO FJ( C1, C2, C3 )
SELECT @c1, ISNULL( MAX( C2 ) + 1, 1 ), @c3
  FROM FJ;
```

This way will be safer.

See ya!